# JPQL Restrictions

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it bad to write JPQL in java files instead of using Specifications and Criterias?. Can anyone give your thoughts on this? JPQL is written in normal String and the respective query is created using entityManager whereas specification and Criteria are provided by JPA itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's totally fine. Do what works best for you. The main use cases for JPA Criteria are that it can be type safe i.e. compile time checkable if you are using the static metamodel and that it can be used for dynamic queries. If your query is static, I would recommend that you just use JPQL in your Java files directly.

Comment: Also, some IDEs now support syntax and error highlighting for JPQL queries, so it doesn't feel much different from writing regular code